# Repair boot after new system board not working,

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10

My laptop needed a new board after some power issues. After the repair the laptop continuously only logs into Windows 10. I booted into a live USB and tried boot repair. Here is the log from that: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/2x6Z7X9jnc/
I am not sure how to get my old grub back. I do not quite know what steps to take next. It is clear my  OS is present but for some reason I am not able to boot into it.

Comment: You replaced the equivalent of the central nervous system of your device.  Reinstall the OS.

Comment: In the boot repair log my old grub is present at a physical location. I just think that windows is somehow able to gain boot priority. I am not afraid to reinstall the OS that would be an option, but I am not sure why this wouldn't just work.

Comment: If the issue is boot priority, you need to change it in your UEFI/BIOS firmware settings. Check the documentation for your device.

Comment: I recommend the use of advanced options in boot repair. Then you can check mark few things you want to repair as opposed to running the "recommended repair options". I recommend following the steps in this link.
https://linuxhint.com/ubuntu_boot_repair_tutorial/

Comment: I resolved the issue. The problem was that grub installation went missing or got overwritten by the MS bootloader. I installed grub following instructions from here: https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd
I had some problems as grub installer was having trouble finding the EFI mount point. This other stack exchange helped with that: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/589390/grub-install-error-cannot-find-efi-directory-reinstalling-grub-boot-loader-w helped with that. Thanks!

Comment: @ngopalan This is a Q&A site. If you have an answer, kindly post it as an answer below. It would be great if your contribution was able to help future visitors